Google Sheets - complex search formula - finding a value next to a string to replace conditionally with array formula
I need to check a column of values and assign them the correct type. This is partially achieved as there is another column that has the classifications, but I need to make some corrections. The values contain strings of characters that if found, should allow be to reclassify them. I need to locate those strings and compare them to a reference sheet, that has the types that I need.
I have prepared a spreadsheet to show what I mean:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klBqmY00h6uQXXsl1-d0pnbQUw04SzIJzMo7Lq5KCMw/edit?usp=sharing
I cannot use something like xlookup as it doesn't allow to look for a partial match and I cannot use regematch that can find me the strings, as that will only get me boolean. And all of that need to be in array formula.
Does anyone have an idea how to do something like that?

You can use XLOOKUP as follows:
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(LEFT(A2:A),Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,B2:B))


For strings that begin with an arbitrary number of uppercase letters [A-Z], use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"[A-Z]*"),Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,B2:B))



Thank you :) This is not the solution for me unfortunately. I have made the example too simplistic and didn't stress enough that the string is of arbitrary length. I have made some changes to the file to represent it. Do you see what I mean now?
